# CEC-Client Turns TV Off, but Not On Again

Tags: cec-client

I'm using the cec-utils shell commands to turn my tv on and off via RPi.

```
echo 'on 0' | cec-client -s -d 1

echo 'standby 0' | cec-client -s -d 1
```

The standby/off command works fine, but the on command doesn't seem to work. Anybody know how I could go about troubleshooting? Anything else I can try? I haven't been able to find others with a similar issue. Thanks!

Comment: the TV may be shut down, so it is unable to respond to any commands

Answer (score 1):

What kind of TV do you have? I am running into the same issue using a Panasonic TV running CEC 1.4. Found the CEC version using:

```
echo "scan" | cec-client RPI -s -d 1
```

This showed no TV after putting it into standby. This could be the clue that leads to an explenation why the TV won't respond to cec-client calls when in standby.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if your display has "eco" or "power saving" mode turned on. For certain Samsung displays using digital signage software, those features being turned on can limit network control when the devices are powered off so you may have similar issues using CEC.

Also, what is your power supply for the RPi? If it is powered by a USB on the TV, turning off the display will most likely stop power from being sent to the USB ports but you didn't mention anything about the RPi rebooting every time the display is powered off so I suspect that is not the case.